# loop to count how many time the column has a different character

Tags: python, pandas, loops, logic

I have a dataframe shown below:

I would like to count how many time the "code" column has a different character from the Key column group:
Ex: in this example the first group has two S but one Q then will count one. The second group it does not have a different char. The third group has three F but one N then will count the total 2

The loop should look at the the Key column and count 1 if there is any different char, then calculate the total number of counts.

The result is a new datframe that has two rows ( inside the red line circles )

[image]

```
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Key': ['111*1', '111*2','111*3', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3','333*4', '444*1'],
        'code': ['S', 'S','Q', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F','N', 'C']}
  
# Create DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have not yet understood exactly what the desired output is. Can you just add an example of the dataframe you want to output?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you don't want duplicates... I recommend splitting the Key column then drop_duplicates.

```
df = {'Key': ['111*1', '111*2','111*3', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3','333*4', '444*1'],
        'code': ['S', 'S','Q', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F','N', 'C']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[['Keya', 'Keyb']] = df['Key'].str.split('\\*', expand=True, regex=True)
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates(keep= False, subset=['code', 'Keya'], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['Keya', 'Keyb'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

results

```
     Key code
2  111*3    Q
8  333*4    N
9  444*1    C
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I do not want the last row. I just want any change of a each group of Key column. Index 9 has one group ( 444*1), so it does not have any change. I just want index 2 & 8

Comment: I just updated your code below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
df = {'Key': ['111*1', '111*2','111*3', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3','333*4', '444*1'],
        'code': ['S', 'S','Q', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F','N', 'C']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[['Keya', 'Keyb']] = df['Key'].str.split('\\*', expand=True, regex=True)
df = df.groupby(['Keya']).filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
df.drop_duplicates(keep= False, subset=['code', 'Keya'], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['Keya', 'Keyb'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).